# Storage in SQLite Database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am creating a teacher review Android Application.

As of now, I plan to create ~900 tables, each representing a professor.
Each table entry will have a field for user comments on the teacher.
Each time a user adds a comment, a new entry is added under that professor

Is this a logical way to go about this? I feel like there could be a more
efficient way of doing this. Also, will having 900 tables be too
much for MySQLite?

I was also thinking about having 1 table that will contain all the professors, and have the user comments as a field. Then, when every new comment is added I would somehow add 1 extra field. I don't think this uses databases properly, but is it possible (to +1 the number of fields)

Answer (score 7):

You do not want 900 tables, you more than likely want one Teacher table with 900 entries.  You may want to read up on some [database design principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_design) and the [Relational Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_model).  The most helpful part of the links may be the examples in the Relational Model.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you read a few articles on database design basics.

Here is a pretty good one that should get you started on the right track:

[Fundamentals of Relational Database Design](http://www.deeptraining.com/litwin/dbdesign/FundamentalsOfRelationalDatabaseDesign.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Without going into it to deep you will need at least one table for all professors, one table for all users and one table for the comments.

```
create table tbl_professor (id integer primary key, name text, ...)
create table tbl_user (id integer primary key, name text, ...)
create table tbl_comment (user_id integer, professor_id integer, thecomment text, ...)
```